# Navigation object is null; why?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, foreign-key-relationship

I have a **Customer** and an **Order** table. The Order table contains a **CustomerId** field that points to **Customer.Id** column. I am retrieving an Order using following

```
var order = (from a in context.Order 
where a.id == OrderId select a).FirstOrDefault();
```

There is another **Auditing** table that has a CustomerId column also.  I am creating an entry in Auditing table and wants to update CustomerId from the order getting from query above, however, order.customer object is null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that there is order with id == OrderId in context.Order?

Comment: Check the value of `OrderId`, and check to make sure that there is actually an order with an ID specified by `OrderId`. Do the second part using a database tool, not entity framework.

Comment: Are you just letting EF do it's thing, or using DataAnnotations or FluentAPI?

Comment: That's because it is LazyLoaded. Change it to eagerloading.

Comment: @Leo: change what and where?

Comment: OrderId is valid. Its returning a row; just that Customer object is null

Comment: Customer is null because you are only pulling from the `Order` table.  If you want customer data you need to include the customer table.

Comment: @paqogomez: can you you provide answer with example?

Comment: Then you need to give more information. It means that customer in this row is really null, how do you set it? Could you provide code for classes and instantiation?

Comment: @paqogomez he also can use "virtual Customer Customer {get; set;}" in Order class and it will be ok. Added: NO, there is CustomerId field and you really need to use `var customer = context.Customer.Find(order.CustomerId)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing that there is a `Customer` navigation property on your `Order` entity with a `CustomerID` field. You will need to explicity load the `Customer` entity by using the `Include` function.

```
var order = (from a in context.Order.Include("Customer") 
where a.id == OrderId select a).FirstOrDefault();

// Check if the result is null
if(order != null)
{
    /// Do stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To include your customer data you would include the table like this code below.

```
var order = (from a in context.Order 
             where a.id == OrderId select a)
                                    .Include(b => b.Customer)
                                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

There needs to be a link between Order and Customer for this to work however.

Comment: +1. If it still returns `null` you'd better check the entities themselves. Remember that `FirstOrDefault()` returns `null` if nothing is found.

Comment: Actually Include is not an option where you have placed in syntax above. However, I can use an Include after context.Order as @DaveB suggested in his response.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution:

```
var order = (from a in context.Order 
where a.id == OrderId select a).FirstOrDefault();
var customer = context.Customer.Find(order.CustomerId);
```